# Map unsigned byte to Java types (JNI)

Tags: java, java-native-interface, unsigned

I have declared this native method.

```
public  native  int SentApduToIcCard(byte[] apdu, int apdulen, byte[]data);
```

In native code, `byte` is unsigned. However, in Java unsigned `byte`s are not available.

I need to send values outside the `byte` range of Java to the native code. Eg:

```
    sendBuff[0] = 0x00;
    sendBuff[1] = 0xa4;
    sendBuff[2] = 0x04;
    sendBuff[3] = 0x00;
    sendBuff[4] = 0x0b;
    sendBuff[5] = 0xa0;
    sendBuff[6] = 0x00;
    sendBuff[7] = 0x00;
    sendBuff[8] = 0x05;
    sendBuff[9] = 0x82;
    sendBuff[10] = 0x00;
    sendBuff[11] = 0x00;
    sendBuff[12] = 0x00;
    sendBuff[13] = 0x00;
    sendBuff[14] = 0x00;
    sendBuff[15] = 0x02;
```

Is there a workaround to this problem?

Comment: I wouldn't expect any problems using signed bytes in Java and expecting them to be mapped to the right unsigned byte in JNI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast values to `byte`, and this will work as expected.

```
sendBuff[1] = (byte) 0xa4;
```